# How to make OSX application that just runs opens some file type and runs arbitrary Ruby code?

Tags: ruby, macos

It's trivial to make a program executable from shell - just put `#!/usr/bin/ruby` on top, `chmod +x` it and done. Unfortunately OSX won't let me associate file type with such scripts - it requires its `.app`s instead. This sort of distinction doesn't seem to exist on other operating systems.

What's the simplest way of making such `.app`, which would merely execute some arbitrary Ruby code?

Answer (score 2):

You could [use Automator](http://developer.apple.com/appleapplications/transformscriptintoaction.html) or create an [AppleScript application using "do shell script"](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2002/tn2065.html) to execute your Ruby script.

Comment: And how would I associate AppleScript snippet with a file type?

Comment: The AppleScript application that you'll create will run as is. You won't need to associate it with a file type. There are two ways to create one: Xcode has a template for a Cocoa-AppleScript application. Alternatively, with the AppleScript editor, you can also save your script as an application.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Script Editor has "Save as Application Bundle" option, which creates foo.app which I can associate with file types.